# Simple program compile error with C, 'Too few arguments' for 'fgets'

Tags: c

I'm learning C from a textbook but cannot see why this does not compile. Code::Blocks states there is too few arguments at 'fgets'. I am assuming 'buffer' is storing keyboard input to volatile memory & fgets should be waiting for arguments from input & Enter.

Any help &/or explanation much appreciated if possible! Thanks

```
/*ex02-05.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)

{
    char buffer[256];
    printf("Enter your name and press Enter:\n");

    fgets(buffer);

    printf("\nYour name has %d characters and spaces",
            strlen(buffer));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @underscore_d Unhelpful

Comment: My questions weren't rhetorical: the first two were counter-questions to encourage critical thought, which I don't feel is unhelpful, and for the rest, I was genuinely asking: does this textbook teach the wrong signature for `fgets()`, and if so, what is its title?

Comment: @Xiphos Just in case your book talks about `gets` instead of `fgets` (which indeed only takes one parameter), throw that book away. That function is too old and insecure. As soon as you use it, your program can crash.

Comment: Apologies I misconstrued due to downvotes (which I am unsure why) it is a SAMS textbooks. It does state 'fgets', I will inform the publisher. Thanks for input, I will check for missing parameters and research syntax going forward :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) takes 3 arguments. This is the prototype:

```
   char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

So change

```
fgets(buffer);
```

to

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
```

Also, note that `fgets()` will read the *newline* character if the buffer has enough space. If this is something you don't want, then you can strip it with:

```
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
```

---

As suggested by @Sebastian, you can also use  `#define` the size:

```
#define SIZE 256

int main(void)
{

    ...
    fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily use `sizeof buffer` in this context - why not make it a constant, then initialize `buffer` with it? Less chance of breakage that way if he later reuses this assignment code with a heap-allocated buffer.

Comment: Instead of a macro you could also use an enum: `enum { SIZE = 256 };`

Comment: @melpomene Sir does it have any advantage over using macro ?

Comment: @ameyCU It respects proper scoping; e.g. declaring a local variable `{ int SIZE; }` isn't an error. Some debuggers don't know about macros, but they know about enums.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help. New terminology for my lexicon & new concepts I have learned, much appreciated.